# Remove validation error after rejecting changes on DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I have a `DataGrid`, which is bound to a typed `DataTable`, like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyTypedDataTable}" ... />
```

This `DataGrid` also has a `RowValidationRule`. Everything works OK exept in one case: when there is an error in a row and I press the Undo Button (`MyTypedDataTable.RejectChanges()`); the validation error is still there and the data in that row is still the same. In cases when there are no errors, `RejectChanges()` works normally.

How can I make the validation error disappear? Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Comment: you should consider looking at where the code executes, is it on the client or server and do you need to refresh the page?

Comment: @MrFox It is not a web application...

Comment: i use ColumnChanging and SetRowError for validation. i have no problems with that. maybe you can post your RowValidationRule stuff?

Comment: @blindmeis How do you set row error? I thought that is done by ValidationRule.

Answer (score 0):

i use this and it works in my projects.

```
public class RowDataValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        BindingGroup group = (BindingGroup)value;
        foreach (var item in group.Items)
        {
            DataRowView rowView = item as DataRowView;
            DataRow row;

            if (rowView != null)
                row = rowView.Row;
            else
                row = item as DataRow;

            if (row != null && row.HasErrors)
            {
                var errorColumns = row.GetColumnsInError();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var column in errorColumns)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(row.GetColumnError(column));
                }

                return new ValidationResult(false, sb.ToString());
            }

        }
        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```

xaml

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyListItems, Mode=OneWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}">
            <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
                <Base:RowDataValidationRule />
            </DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
</DataGrid>
```